# Should the sense of the Greek μονογενής (only-begotten vs unique) in John be understood from Pagan Greek religion or Scripture?

Tags: greek, john, jesus, translation-philosophy, hermeneutical-approaches

Should the sense of the Greek μονογενής (only-begotten vs unique) in John be understood from Pagan Greek religion or Scripture?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107272/discussion-on-question-by-thomas-pearne-should-the-sense-of-the-greek-).

Comment: Psalm 22:20 says, "Deliver my soul from the sword; my darling from the power of the dog."  The "darling" is the Hebrew "יחיד (yahid)", meaning "only", translated as μονογενη in the LXX.

Comment: @RadzMatthewC.Brown   How do you apply that reference?

Comment: shows your assessment's faulty. monogenes can't mean only begotten except when deemed as a metaphor

Comment: @RadzMatthewC.Brown That's absurd.  You show one example of a metaphor and  ignore the others in BDAG-1 that are not?

Comment: what's absurd? you misunderstand my comment. did i reject that the rendering only begotten in reference to Christ? lol i even use NASB that has it. THAT is the metaphor. The literal meaning is only, unique, only-one-of-its-kind

Comment: @RadzMatthewC.Brown No, I read you correctly.  You take one example of a metaphorical usage in a poetic book and ignore all the rest in BDAG.

Comment: monogenes can't mean only begotten except when deemed as a metaphor. modern scholarship know better now. for example monogenes theos for 400 years not known among the churches! Now monogenes was correctly have been deemed as 'only'

Comment: @RadzMatthewC.Brown You are quoting yourself and if you had a legitimate reference that made your point you would have used it.  I know that because you quoted a large section of my paper in yours.  :)

Comment: Please read Monogenes: “Only Begotten” or “One of a Kind”?
by Larry Brigden - https://www.christianstudylibrary.org/comment/reply/35756

Comment: @Dottard I had initially agreed with the Closure as it doesn't cite a specific passage, but given the rarity of monogenes in John, I wonder if this isn't a sufficient 'scope' provided in the Q. Or do we need to cite all 4 passages? Interested in your thoughts, as both a VTC and an Answerer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the sense of *monogenes* is very clearly delineated within scripture and I find that arguments from outside of scripture are dubious and ambiguous.

The first aspect of the use of the word is clear in the gospel accounts. I shall not go into huge detail, though I have done so in a booklet recently published. To be brief, an examination of the use of the word relating to those who benefited from miracles done by Jesus shows that both mother and father and both son and daughter are included.

Therefore, gender (both of parent and progeny) is irrelevant in the use of the word as scripture uses it.

But generation is important. It is a matter of generations : father to daughter, mother to son, father to son, whatever.

Thus the first principle. **Generational but not gender specific.**

The second principle becomes clear when one considers the use of the word in relation to Isaac. Ishmael, was, of course, the first child produced by Abraham. But Ishmael is decidedly not the *monogenes* of Abraham. 'This shall not be thine heir' says God.

Ishmael was born of convenience. Ishmael was born of a woman not a wife. Ishmael was not born of a real **union**. I stress **union**. This union is important in the consideration of what *monogenes* means - **as used within scripture.**

It becomes clear with thorough consideration (again I cannot go into vast detail, though I have done so in published form) what *monogenes* means, as regards divine principles and divine purposes.

It is a special relationship. And I emphasise **relationship.**

It is not merely the fact of the 'first born'. It is a unique relationship. I disagree with the concept of 'one and only' or 'solitary' but there is a vein of truth in that wording. But the 'solitary' 'unique' 'one and only' translation does not convey what is most important. The relationship.

'Solitary' 'unique' 'one and only' leaves the *monogenes* alone, almost destitute.

That concept, in my own view (and I would say that in strict regard of scriptural usage) is not correct. It leaves out the focus of the word in regard to the relationship between the generations.

Thus *monogenes* expresses a non-gender (therefore a spiritual) relationship, It is not of nature. Isaac was born supernaturally from the union of one past bearing and one as good as dead.

Now **that** is *monogenes*.

Only when we examine the use of the word - as used in scripture - do we see what we are being taught.

- not of nature : of spirit
- generational
- the result of a union
- a unique relationship - like no other

All of this is conveyed in these few mentions within holy writ of the Greek word, *monogenes*. But nowhere - absolutely nowhere - else would we discover such information.

Solidly founded on roots in the Hebrew scripture, firmly bedded in the history of God's dealings with his own chosen people, and further expressed in the miracles done, uniquely, by Jesus Christ himself, attended by the power of God : this is our learning, these are our precedents.

And all of this is documented carefully for us by chosen apostles of Jesus Christ that we might learn from them.

All we do, ourselves, is notice what they have done.

And thus, and thus alone, do we learn what the word conveys when applied to the Son of God, the Son of the Father's love.

Comment: +1 Nigel....... and very nicely and eloquently related

Comment: Wonder how this works with Judges 11:34 LXX, psalm 24:16LXX, psalm 34:17LXX

Comment: @NihilSineDeo I cannot comment until you tell me why you are quoting those references.

Comment: I should be able to take at least one of those four bullet points and fit them into those verses. You’re saying that all those points are valid about Jesus. Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: I have not actually commented on the translation of the word. The question was about where to look in order to find information. For the Greek word one looks to the Greek scriptures. But the LXX is not Greek scripture. It is Hebrew scripture, translated into Greek. It is not inspired.

Answer (score 1):

μονογενής (monogenés) is a word of the Greek New Testament that occurs 9 times, whose meaning is contentious because of the Arian vs Trinitarian controversy.  The contention is best illustrated by its translation in the earliest version, Jerome’s Vulgate of 400 AD.

- 3 times it applies to a parent’s only child (Luke 7:12, 8:42, 9:38) and is translated “unicus”, unique.
- once it is used to describe Isaac (Heb 11:17) and is translated “unigenitus”, only begotten.
- 5 times it is used to describe Jesus (John 1:14, 18, 3:16, 18, 1 John 4:9) and is translated “unigenitus”, only begotten.

Thus, the Vulgate (both Jerome and Clementine texts) adopted an uneven practice when rendering monogenes which was followed by Tyndale, the KJV, NKJV and many more until the late 20th century.  Many modern versions since the late 20th century including NIV, NRSV, ESV, etc, uniformly translate this word as “only”, “unique” or equivalent.

The point at issue here is the cognate root of the second part of the word – is it related to gennao (beget, bear), or to genos (class, kind)?  Modern linguistic analysis (eg, see BDAG) is firmly of the view that the latter is correct.  Indeed, if the New Testament writers had intended “only begotten” then they would have used the word, monogennetos; but they did not.  This conclusion is further shown in other instances of monogenes in the LXX such as Ps 21:21 (LXX), 22:20 (NASB), Ps 24:16 (LXX), 25:16 (NASB) where the meaning cannot be “only begotten”.

BDAG, which says the words is compound of monos + genos, provides two meanings for this word as:

1. **pertaining to being the only one of its kind within a specific relationship, *one and only***, eg, Heb 11:17, Luke 7:12, 9:38, 8:42
2. **Pertaining to being the only one of its kind or class, *unique (in kind)*** of something that is the only example of its category, eg, John 3:16, 18, 1 John 4:9, John 1:15, 18.  BDAG also adds this: "The renderings *only, unique* may be quite adequate for all its occurrences here."

Lastly, the correct meaning of monogenes is clear from its use in Heb 11:17.  Isaac was neither Abraham’s first nor only child; however, Isaac was, by virtue of his miraculous conception and birth, and being a progenitor of Christ, unique among Abraham’s numerous children.

πρωτότοκος (prototokos) is a very different word from monogenes.  Its literal meaning is clearly "first born".  BDAG provides two basic meanings:

1. literally, **pertaining to birth order, *firstborn***, eg, Matt 1:25, Luke 2:7, Heb 11:28
2. **pertaining to having special status associated with a firstborn, *firstborn***, eg, Rom 8:29, Heb 1:6, Rev 1:5, 2:8, Col 1:15, 18.

Note that in the case of Jesus in Col 1:15, Jesus cannot literally (biologically) be "firstborn" as the same word is used in V18 to denote "first born of the dead".  Since Jesus was not the first resurrected (there were many before Him), its idiomatic meaning is "the most important", which is obviously true.

Comment: Then you missed the whole paragraph above which said "Lastly, the correct meaning of monogenes is clear from its use in Heb 11:17. Isaac was neither Abraham’s first nor only child; however, Isaac was, by virtue of his miraculous conception and birth, and being a progenitor of Christ, unique among Abraham’s numerous children."

Comment: The definitions in BDAG are those in BOLD - and included the whole definition.

Comment: "Since Jesus was not the first resurrected (there were many before Him)", Who are these?  Is their resurrection recorded in the bible?

Comment: Really @AlexBalilo??  Have you not read about them at all?  What of the Widow of Zarephath's daughter (1 Kings 17:17-24), the Shunamite's son (2 Kings 4:32-37), The man landing on Elisha's bones (2 kings 13:20, 21), The widow of Nain's son (Luke 7:11-17), Jarius' daughter (Mark 5:35-43), Lazarus (John 11:39-44), the many saints (Matt 27:52, 53) - these were all (chronologically) before Jesus' resurrection.

Comment: I apologize. I should  have been more specific. Were they resurrected like Jesus was resurrected to everlasting life?

Comment: @AlexBalilo they couldn’t have been since He is the Life (eternal). One has to be in Him to attain eternal life and these were prior to the New Covenant which nullified the Old covenant.